# How to break from a for loop on a given UI event?

Tags: javascript, async-await, addeventlistener

I need to break from a for loop on a given UI event.  I worked out the approach shown below; however, it is unpredictable and I have a sense that this is not the right way to do this.

In this minimal example I break from the for loop when the user clicks the document by awaiting a setTimeout at each iteration of the for loop.  This await allows for `stop` to be set to `true`, which causes the break to happen.

This for loop just logs a zero to the console.  A more practical use case may be to stop adding list elements to an unordered list given a UI event e.g., the keypress event.

```
let zeros = new Array(10000).fill(0);

(async () => {

    let stop = false;
    document.addEventListener('click', async ()=>{
        console.log('click');
        stop = true;
        await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 100)); //2
        stop = false;
    });

    for (let zero of zeros) {
        await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r, 100)); //1
        if (stop) {
            break;
        }
        console.log(zero);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish this by adding your function to the event loop instead of using a for loop

using your example, a solution could look like this:

```js
let zeroes = new Array(10000).fill(0);

let index = 0
let stop = false
document.addEventListener('click', async ()=>{
  console.log('click');
  stop = true;
});

function loopOverArray(index){
  if(!stop && index < zeroes.length){
    requestAnimationFrame(loopOverArray)
  }
  console.log(zeroes[index])
  index++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setInterval`. No need to complicate things with `await` and `setTimeout`. Not sure why you're setting `stop` back to false after setting it to true though...

```js
let stop = false;

document.addEventListener('click', () => (stop = true));

const id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('running');
  if (stop) {
    console.log('stopped');
    clearInterval(id);
  }
});
```

---

To do this while iterating through an array:

```js
    const arr = new Array(1000).fill(0);
    
    let stop = false;

    document.addEventListener('click', () => (stop = true));
    
    let index = 0;
    
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(arr[index++]);
      if (stop || index === arr.length) {
        console.log('stopped');
        clearInterval(id);
      }
    });
```